# Remove Bokeh Logo in HoloViews

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh, holoviews

Is it possible to remove the Bokeh logo from plots generated with HoloViews? Nothing against it... it's just that it may not make sense to display it in certain reports. :)

I know that in Bokeh I can simply do:

```
p = bkp.figure(...)
...
p.toolbar.logo = None
```

**UPDATE**

Here's my import section:

```
import sys
import os

import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)
import random
random.seed(0)

import pandas as pd
from bokeh.models import HoverTool
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension("bokeh", logo=False)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently (as of holoviews 1.9.1) the option to disable the bokeh logo in the toolbar is not directly exposed, but you can supply a so called `finalize_hook` which lets you modify the plot directly. You can add such a hook directly on the `ElementPlot` to set it globally:

```
def disable_logo(plot, element):
    plot.state.toolbar.logo = None
hv.plotting.bokeh.ElementPlot.finalize_hooks.append(disable_logo)
```

or set it as a plot option:

```
hv.Curve(range(10)).opts(plot=dict(finalize_hooks=[disable_logo])
```

Comment: Quick comment. That worked for an overlay plot I created (e.g., A * B * C), but it didn't work for a composed plot of overlay objects (e.g., (C + D).cols(1), where C = A1 * B1 and D = A2 * B2). I still see the Bokeh logo in the latter case.

Answer (score 2):

```
hv.extension("bokeh",logo=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, James! But that didn't work for me... I still see the Bokeh logo after creating overlay plots in Jupyter notebook. By the way, I attended your webinar yesterday and it was excellent! I'm excited to learn more about HoloViews and Datashader. Keep up the great work!

Comment: Currently we don't expose this option directly you could disable it globally for now by adding a hook to that effect. See my post for details.

Comment: D'oh!  I didn't read the question closely enough; logo=False is about the logo at the top of the notebook, not the one on each plot as you're asking about.

Answer (score 2):

To remove the Bokeh logo for more complicated layouts, I think you need to render it to a Bokeh figure, and then use Bokeh's native method to remove it.

```
layout = C + D
plot = renderer.get_plot(layout)
p = plot.state
p.children[0].toolbar.logo = None
show(p)
```

[image: Remove Bokeh Logo for Layout]

Comment: Thanks! And how did you define the variable `renderer`?

Comment: `renderer = hv.renderer('bokeh')`

Comment: I created an extension mod to do this in a more straightforward manner.
`Mod(logo=False).apply(bar)`
https://holoext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/modifying_toolbar_tools.html

Answer (score 2):

**1)** This is almost the same as philippjfr answer, but slightly shorter **using hooks**:

```
def remove_bokeh_logo(plot, element):
    plot.state.toolbar.logo = None

hv.Scatter(df).opts(hooks=[remove_bokeh_logo])
```

**2)** And there's Andrew's answer, **rendering the plot as bokeh and then removing the logo**:

```
from bokeh.plotting import show

hv_plot = hv.Scatter(df)
bokeh_plot = hv.render(hv_plot, backend='bokeh')
bokeh_plot.toolbar.logo = None

show(bokeh_plot)
```