# Turn active tools for NdOverlay object off

Tags: python, bokeh, holoviews

I have an overlay figure using hvplots and would like to turn all tools off by default. I know that when you have a figure handle, this could be done as described [here](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#setting-the-active-tools), using `plot.toolbar.active_drag = None`. However, when trying to use this approach on a `Ndoverlay` object, I get the error `'NdOverlay' object has no attribute 'toolbar'`. I also tried to add the overlay to an empty holoview figure with `fig.add_layout` and `fig.add_glyphs`, but this didn't work either. How can I achieve the desired behavior?

MWE:

```
import numpy as np
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension('bokeh')

points = [(0.1*i, np.sin(0.1*i)) for i in range(100)]
overlay =hv.NdOverlay({interp: hv.Curve(points[::8]).opts(interpolation=interp, width=600)
                       for interp in ['linear', 'steps-mid', 'steps-pre', 'steps-post']})
overlay
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to do it based on the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47585887/remove-bokeh-logo-in-holoviews) question, by rendering it as a bokeh figure.

```
import numpy as np
import holoviews as hv
from bokeh.plotting import show
hv.extension('bokeh')

points = [(0.1*i, np.sin(0.1*i)) for i in range(100)]
overlay =hv.NdOverlay({interp: hv.Curve(points[::8]).opts(interpolation=interp, width=600)
                       for interp in ['linear', 'steps-mid', 'steps-pre', 'steps-post']})

plot = hv.render(overlay, backend='bokeh')
plot.toolbar.active_drag = None
show(plot)
```